# Approximation of Cauchy distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, approximation, cauchy-distribution

I have a ratio of two random, (dependent or independent) normally distributed variables.

Knowing that the resulting Cauchy-distribution does not produce any moments. May I ask: Is there an approximation to a Cauchy distribution? Can I still get something out of my set of ratios?

Answer (score 3):

The ratio of two arbitrary normal random variables is not in general Cauchy.

Even the ratio of two jointly normal random variables is [not in general Cauchy](http://mrvar.fdv.uni-lj.si/pub/mz/mz1.1/cedilnik.pdf).

Let's assume you're dealing with a ratio that does have a Cauchy distribution. Then all manner of quantities converge - including quantiles and many functions of quantiles, trimmed and winsorized moments, and cdfs.

Answer (score 3):

First, the ratio is Cauchy only if the denominator distribution is centered at 0. 
In any cases, the statistics on the ratio of $y$ and $x$ can be approximated as:

$$\hat{\mu}_{y:x} = \mu_y/\mu_x + \sigma^2_x * \mu_y  / \mu_x^3 + cov(x,y) * \sigma^2_x * \sigma^2_y / \mu_x^2$$
$$\hat{\sigma}^2_{y:x} = \sigma^2_x\times\mu_y / \mu_x^4 + \sigma^2_y / \mu_x^2 - 2 * cov(x,y) * \sigma^2_x * \sigma^2_y / \mu_x^3$$

if one supposes that the variances are neglictable with respect to the mean (see the post [How to parameterize the ratio of two normally distributed variables, or the inverse of one?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3640/how-to-parameterize-the-ratio-of-two-normally-distributed-variables-or-the-inve)).

However, I think that as suggested in other answers, using the quantiles would be more appropriated.

Comment: It's difficult to see how either expression is a good approximation because the corresponding *correct* moments are undefined (for the mean) and infinite (for the variance)!

Answer (score 2):

Your question assumes that the distribution of the denominator is centered at 0. If this is so, the median and the mad will converge (to 0 and 1, respectively).

[image]

```r
nn <- exp(seq(log(10), log(100000), l=20))
aa <- rep(NA, length(nn))
bb <- rep(NA, length(nn))
for(i in 1:length(nn)){
    x1 <- rt(nn[i], df=1)
    aa[i] <- median(x1)
    bb[i] <- mad(x1, constant=1)
}
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(bb, type="l", ylab="mad", xlab="log sample size")
plot(aa, type="l", ylab="med", xlab="log sample size")
```

btw, you have to change the consistency factor in the computation of the mad
from $1.4826=1/\Phi^{-1}(0.75)$ to $1=1/t^{-1}_{0.75}$ (the quantile function of the Cauchy distribution evaluated at $q=0.75$)